# Undo changes made in git commit and move them to a different branch

Tags: git

I have a commit that has made changes to files A,B,C,D,E. 
This commit has been pushed to a remote server.

I would like to take the changes to files C and E and move them to a separate branch as they were pushed while unstable and we will not have time to 'stabilize' them before release.

I suppose what I'm asking is to get a previous commit on C and E to the HEAD and have those changes made be put into their own branch on the side for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a branch starting at the current `HEAD`:

```
git branch newbranch
```

Undo the changes to `HEAD`:

```
git revert --no-commit <the-faulty-commit>
git checkout -- A B D
git commit
```

You can later either merge with `newbranch` (but make sure to pick the right merge strategy, or the `revert` will take precedence) or `revert` the `revert`.

Comment: Didn't you mean `git checkout -- A B D`? Those are the files he want to keep.